# How to plot individual points in Matlab at certain locations?

Tags: matlab, plot, appearance

I have the following graph :

[image]

Each line changes according to 3 values : `1 2 3` .. However plotting anything less than 5000 will not show on the graph (axis min size is 5000), so I can't plot them directly. How can I show that these lines are changing according to either of these 3 values ?? Any way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an offset value to the data you can not display properly so that you caan observe the relationship between the lines

Answer (score 1):

The [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) function gives two y-axes enabling you to display two sets of data on one graph even though the relative values of the data are different.

For more control you can superimpose two axes objects. See [Using Multiple X- and Y-Axes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-multiple-x-and-y-axes.html).